# In JavaScript, 'onbeforeunload' not working until we clicked on opened window

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, 'onbeforeunload' not working until we clicked on opened window.

Please suggest me any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post any code showing what you were doing or give any more context as to what you were looking for?

Comment: 1. Suppose, I opened a jsp using window.open();
2. Now, I used 
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        alert("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
    }
3. This code executes only if i clicked anywhere on opened window.
4. If i haven't clicked on opened window, this alert has not come on closing the window.

Comment: What browser? How are you opening the window? How are you closing it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I don't think you're using it correctly. You need to return a string, not use an alert.

Parent page:

```
<script>
var w;
function x(){
  w = window.open('test2.html');
}
</script>
<button onclick="x();">open</button>
<button onclick="w.close();">close</button>
```

Popup:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload=function (e) {
  e.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
   return e.returnValue;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
popup
</body>
</html>
```